# Showing that if $\lim_{x\to\infty}xf(x)=l,$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0.$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $l \in\mathbb{R} $ and $ f:(0,\infty) \to \Bbb R $ be a function such that $ \lim_{x\to \infty} xf(x)=l $ .

Prove that  $ \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0 $.

Any help would be appreciated - I found this difficult to prove

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} xf(x)=l$

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x}=0$

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x}xf(x) =\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)$

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x}xf(x)=\left(\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} xf(x)\right)=0l=0$

$\boxed{\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0}$

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\frac l{\lim_{x\to\infty} x}$$

Comment: Who tells you that such a limit exists?

Comment: @Lano, isn't it legal to write $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\frac l{\lim_{x\to\infty} x}?$$

Comment: Only if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists, and you have to prove it.

Comment: @Lano, I think the question assumes the existence of the limit, for example $$\lim_{x\to0}x\cdot \sin\frac1x=0(l \text{ here} ),$$ but $$\lim_{x\to0} \sin\frac1x$$ does not exist, right?

Comment: There's no need for such an assumption:$\left(\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} xf(x)\right)=0l=0$

Comment: @Lano, then how do you explain the anomaly mentioned in the last comment?

Comment: Your limit is for x which tends to 0.. -_-

Comment: I think @Lano is right. lab bhattacharjee Following your assertion, notice that even when the $\lim $ does exist, we might have an undefined answer to $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \frac{l}{\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x}}$
which contradicts what we know. 
for example, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \sin \frac{1}{x} = \frac{0(l here)}{\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x}}
$ where we end up with undefined case  but what we know is $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \sin \frac{1}{x} = 0$